raspberry pi ota update
I need some of the best strategies for implementing Raspberry Pi OTA updates in security systems. How can we ensure that the updates maintain smooth functionality and strong protection without causing disruptions?
Additionally, how do you handle common issues like connectivity problems, firmware compatibility challenges, and security risks during the OTA update process?
Does anyone have practical experience or tips on optimizing Raspberry Pi OTA updates to not only improve performance but also minimize downtime and protect data privacy?
Looking forward to hearing your thoughts and insights!

Welcome. Rpi OS has a systemd service, apt-daily-upgrade, that is enabled by default.  It is not unique to Rpi OS, however, and questions about it would be more appropriate on Unix & Linux.

please ask one focused question ... delete the rest
